# Angular: accessing directive attributes in controller constructor

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, attributes, angularjs-scope

(Using Angular 1.5)

I am trying to use the following design pattern for my angular app:

```
angular.module("app").directive("MyDirective", MyDirective);

function MyDirective () {
  return {
    bindToController: {
      someId: "=",
      otherAttr: "@"
    },
    controller: ["$attrs", MyController],
    controllerAs: "ctrl"
  };
}

function MyController ($attrs) {
  var self = this;
  console.log(self);
  console.log($attrs);
}
```

I use my directive in my HTML like this:

```
<my-directive someId="someParentScope.model._id" otherAttr="1">
```

In the console, for `self` I see:

```
Object { otherAttr: undefined, someId: undefined }
```

and for `$attrs` I see:

```
Object { $attr: Object, $$element: Object, otherattr: "1",
  someid: "someParentScope.model._id", otherAttr: undefined, someId: undefined,
  $$observers: Object }
```

How may I accomplish what I am trying to accomplish (i.e. passing data from parent scope into my directive controller constructor), and why is even my single binding ("@" binding) `otherAttr` undefined in the controller constructor?  Is this design pattern is flawed/misguided?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you have the naming conventions wrong on the directive, you should define the name on directive attribute as "data-content" and use on the controller as "dataContent"

Take a look this demo i've done

```
// directive HTML    
<my-directive some-id="name" other-attr="1"></my-directive>

//app.js 
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          bindToController: {
            someId: "=",
            otherAttr: "@"
          },
          controller: ["$attrs", MyController],
          controllerAs: "ctrl"
        }
      });


function MyController ($attrs) {
  var self = this;
  console.log(self);
  console.log($attrs);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/P3VKdO?p=preview

Comment: Wow--that was it, thanks!
That part wasn't really clear to me from the docs--I thought the camelcase conversion was just something angular would do if you used hyphens in your attribute/directive names.